# Windows 10 hosts file only recognizing one redirect

Tags: windows-10, hosts-file

In my hosts file I have

```
a.b.c.d website1.com
a.b.c.d website2.com
```

Website 1 works just fine, redirecting me to the new website. Website 2 does not. It sometimes tells me that the connection is insecure but does not give me the new site.

One weird thing is that yesterday I put in the address for the second site and it worked for about an hour. Then I went back to the sight and it no longer worked.

Any help?